# Kotlin/Android - Wrap all methods of a class with body

Tags: android, kotlin

Problem: Every access/call to an object should be wrapped with abitrary code.

Example:

```
class Foo constructor() {
 fun doA() {...}
 fun doB() {...}
 fun doC() {...}
 ...
 fun getA() : A {...}
 fun getB() : B {...}
 ...
 fun startAccess()
 fun stopAccess()
}
```

I now want every call to Foo to first call `startAccess()`, execute whatever, e.g. `doA()` and then `stopAccess()`.

My current approach is to have a method that wraps the calls through passing a lambda.

```
fun <T> wrapCall(call: () -> T) : T {
 startAccess()
 val result = call()
 stopAccess()
 return call
}
```

Now every access works as this:

```
fun doA() = wrapCall {
 ...
}

fun getA() = wrapCall {
 ...
}
```

This works fine but leaves me to wrap every method with the `wrapCall`.

Is there another approch like writing an extension method that automates the `wrapCall()` for me so  that I do not have to call it for every method?

Imagine something along where the asterix * means "for all calls to Foo":

```
fun <T> Foo.*(call: () -> T) : T{
 startAccess()
 call()
 stopAccess()
}
```

Unimportant background:
I use a library that runs on a separate thread, all calls to that library must be executed from that separate thread. Its up to the user how this is enforced.
I for now wrapped every access to the library with the generic function to post it on this separate thread and not execute it right away.

Thanks :)!

Comment: What you want to accomplish can be done with so called [Aspect-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). You might want to look into that. I don't know if kotlin has easy ways to do it. I know that for Java there exists AspectJ. It might also work for kotlin. But it's been a long time ago since I worked with that so I can't help you much but maybe it can help you

Comment: your exampls looks fine. just add inline if the doA has shorter piece of code this will reduce memory allocation overhead for each call